# ajax and “Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined”

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### In Chrome console, the message error is :

#### Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

```
    function list(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'adeneme.php',
        data:$('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

         console.log(data);
         $('#snc').html(data);

        },
      error: function(x) {


      console.log(data);    
      $('#snc').html("Error:"+x); 
      }
    });
}
```

**adeneme.php ;**

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["seans"]) && isset($_POST["date"])){
    $seans=$_POST["seans"];
   $tarih=$_POST["date"];

   echo $seans."  ".$tarih;
}
?>
```

**What is going wrong ? What to do ?**

**Edit**: all is done client side.

Comment: It's ``console.log(x);`` instead of ``console.log(data);`` since your naming the parameter in ``error: function(x) {``

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If "all is done client side", why is this question tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

**error** function is getting called.
you are logging data instead it should be console.log(x); inside error callback.

As you are checking existence of for "seans" and "date", make sure that your form has respective elements with name "seans" and "date".

Post your form code in your question so that we could get clear picture on what is wrong ...

Comment: thanks fixed console.log(data) and function(data) but now the message error is [object Object] also checked seans and date

Comment: <form id="form1" method="post" style="display:inline;">
  <p><input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="date" ></p><div id="snc"></div>
  <select id="seans" name="seans">
   <option value="1">09.30-10.30</option>
   <option value="2">10.30-12.00</option>
   <option value="3">12.00-13.00</option>
   <option value="4">13.00-14.30</option>
   <option value="5">14.30-16.00</option>
   <option value="6">16.00-17.30</option>   
   <option value="7">17.30-19.00</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Goruntule" onclick="list()" />
  </form>

Comment: [object Object] in your console?

Comment: no sorry not console alert(data) message [object Object]

Comment: Console message:  Object{readyState: 0, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeader: function ,getResponseHeader: function , overrideMimeType: function...}

Comment: can you remove the space in your echo statement and try? ehco $seans.$tarih;

Comment: Also can you tell me where is your html and where is your PHP placed. I think it might be path issue...

Comment: i cant jsfiddle for ajax

Comment: both in the same folder html and php

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot data type that you get from php file. try this

```
function list(){

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'adeneme.php',
    data:$('#form1').serialize(),
    dataType: "Json"
    success: function (data) {

     console.log(data);
     $('#snc').html(data);

    },
  error: function(x) {


  console.log(data);    
  $('#snc').html("Error:"+x); 
  }
});
```

}

in php file :

```
 if(isset($_POST["seans"]) && isset($_POST["date"])){
      $seans=$_POST["seans"];
      $tarih=$_POST["date"];
      $json_array = array($seans, $tarih);
      echo json_encode($json_array);
  }
```