# $.ajax ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting

> ReferenceError: data is not defined
>   and

```
>NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/WebApplication2/js/test.aspx"
```

But my aspx page is in right directory

I did all these to remove internal server error :

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Code is as per tutorial

Index.html (Callback Data will be posted Here)

```
<body>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Go" />
    <div id="feedback">    </div>


</body>
```

this is My Ajax method :

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.aspx",
        data: {"name=" + name},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#feedback").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

test.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<%Response.Write(Request.Form["name"].ToString()); %>
</div>
</form>
```

similar Posts :

[ajax and “Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803288/ajax-and-uncaught-referenceerror-data-is-not-defined)
[$.ajax() and "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743483/ajax-and-uncaught-referenceerror-data-is-not-defined)
[Ajax data - Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917797/ajax-data-uncaught-referenceerror-date-is-not-defined)

**Edit** : JSLint /JSHint /SharpLinter still not helping much for detecting syntax Error .I need some suggestion for syntax check

there were issue of placing datatype parameter too.. it is not in my case .

I could not able to find something simple there..Please suggest

Comment: I don't see anything in the given code that can cause that error.

Comment: post the raw text of the xhr response.  You can get this with fiddler or the chrome dev tools.

Comment: ok . i am on chrome dev tools .. can you tell me exact option for that ?

Comment: On Console i got this error :NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/WebApplication2/js/test.aspx" ..but my page is on right directory

Comment: 500 isn't 404. Your `test.aspx` is throwing an error.

Comment: i tested test.aspx on browser seperately ..it is fine with hardcoded value ..For name parameter it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ..but name parameter value will come from ajax method ...right ?

Comment: console.log(name) in your click handler to make sure that you're actually passing data. You should be able to gather all sorts of information in your console about the request / response. 500 errors usually generate a log entry in your web server logs that should be helpful too.

Comment: yes it is passing data in console log

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you should pass data as:

```
data: {name: name},
```

---

Also, instead of `data`, try to use some other variable in the success function:

```
success: function (response) {
   $("#feedback").html(response);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't obviously mean anything

Comment: i didnt meant to be rude ... i usually do small homeworks/ changing variables /test with empty data /harcoded data etc. before posting .. i meant to say it doesnt change anything ..including error

Answer (score 1):

ok ..Finally got it working ... error was in  data parameter (after url)

Instead of (this is tutorial Code)

```
data: {"name=" + name1},
```

this worked for me

```
data : {'name':name1},
```

Here is working Code :

script

```
$('#button').click(function () {
var name1="aa";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.aspx",
        data : {'name':name1},
        statusCode: {
            404: function () { $("#messege").text("Page not found"); },
            500: function () { $("#messege").text("internal server error"); }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#messege").html(data); 
        } });
});
```

rest is same .Below link was relevant and helpful

[jquery POST data in aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656833/jquery-post-data-in-aspx-page)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was loading the response in a Bootstrap Modal form but it wasn't declared on the view.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes that can happen if you are using JS with web-pack or with the JS build architecture.

So that time it is good to define the data first and then you can use it.

You can define your data as:

```
let data = {
    // Your data values.
}
```

And then you can use that anywhere in the code.

So while working with JS build architecture you must define the variable first and then you can use that.